# Модуль pygame._sdl2.video, стоит ли использовать?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame, fps

Недавно друг предложил мне создать игру на pygame. Основной игровой процесс происходит на поле состоящем из тайлов, я написал функцию которая рисует видимые человеку тайлы из двумерного массива. Если каждый кадр повторять этот процесс по 30 раз, то fps падает до 5. Но когда я переписал код с помощью pygame._sdl2.video при таком же алгоритме стало 60 fps. Я прочитал что это бета версия ._sdl2 и ее не рекомендуют использовать для проектов.
Стоит ли мне вернуть код обратно или же нет?
(я понимаю что pygame не лучший вариант для игр, но мы остановились на нем)

Comment: Все зависит от того проект какого масштаба ты хочешь реализовать. Для серьёзных проектов это действительно не подойдет. Для любительских — почему бы и нет?